# autohotkey, to go a tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I have a many chrome windows open. Each chrome window has many tabs.

Right now I can only go to the chrome tab if what I want is the active tab by calling the name of the tab directly.

```
!t::
   WinActivate System - Google Sheets - Google Chrome
   Return
```

If the name of the tab is not active, nothing happens when I use the hotkey.

How do I get autohotkey to search through all the tabs and activate the one I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this function with mixed success. It sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> until it either finds the tab title you want or until it finds a tab with the original title. I think you'll find an issue in your case if you have multiple *windows* in addition to multiple *tabs*. You may be able to tweak it to flip between windows as well.

```
; Activate tab in Google Chrome if it exists, return true/false if exist/doesn't exist
ActivateChromeTab(soughtTab)
{
  IfWinNotExist Google Chrome
  {
    return false
  }

  WinActivate Google Chrome
  WinWaitActive Google Chrome
  WinGetTitle, currentTab, A
  firstTab := currentTab

  if (InStr(currentTab, soughtTab) > 0)
  {
    return true
  }

  Loop
  {
    Send {CtrlDown}{Tab}{CtrlUp}
    Sleep 50
    WinGetTitle, currentTab, A
    foundTab := InStr(currentTab, soughtTab) > 0
  }
  Until (foundTab || currentTab == firstTab)

  return foundTab
}
```

Comment: One unfortunate work around with your solution would be to use all of the other browsers like firefox, opera, and god forbid IE...